# Matplotlib Line Graph Shift X-Axis Values and Tick Labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Given the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'YYYYMM':[201603,201503,201403,201303,201603,201503,201403,201303],
         'Count':[5,6,2,7,4,7,8,9],
         'Group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})
df['YYYYMM']=df['YYYYMM'].astype(str).str[:-2]
t=df.pivot_table(df,index=['YYYYMM'],columns=['Group'],aggfunc=np.sum)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
t.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

I'd like to shift the `xaxis` `tick_labels` (years) and the corresponding lines to the right to make room for the `yaxis` `ticks` and `labels`. 
I tried this (after `t.plot(ax=ax)`:

```
ax.set_xlim([-.5,3]) #allow for space below zero and above max value
```

But it only shifted the lines:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to revert to `int` and then use `FormatStrFormatter`:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

df['YYYYMM'] = df['YYYYMM'].astype(str).str[:-2].astype(int)
t = df.pivot_table(df, index=['YYYYMM'], columns=['Group'], aggfunc=np.sum).loc[:, 'Count']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1)
margin = 0.5
t.plot(ax=axes, xticks=t.index.tolist(), xlim=(t.index.min()-margin, t.index.max()+margin), ylim=(t.min().min()-margin, t.max().max()+margin))
axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Including `.loc[:, 'Count']` gets you a different legend.

Comment: Thank-you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import datetime
dates = pd.to_datetime(t.index)
plt.plot(dates, t.Count.A)
plt.plot(dates, t.Count.B)  
plt.xlim(datetime.date(2012,1,1), datetime.date(2017,1,1))
plt.show()
```